# How to create a new feature collection in google earth engine with only a few selected columns from another feature collection?

Tags: gis, google-earth-engine

pretty basic question here but I'm new to google earth engine. I have a feature collection with 42 columns (a shapefile covering one state in the US) and I want to make a new one with only a few of those columns but still covering the entire state (keeping all rows in the attribute table). I have tried using .select and several other functions but have not been able to figure this out yet. Any insights are appreciated!

example code here: shp1 is the name of the feature collection (polygon shapefile). shp2 is the new feature collection I'm trying to make, and test1 and test2 are the columns I want to bring from shp1 to shp2 (along with the geometry).

var shp2 = shp1.select(['test1', 'test2']);

At this point, the result is another feature collection without any columns.

Comment: From what you've said so far, `.select()` is the right tool for what you're trying to do. If you [edit] your question to provide runnable example code which demonstrates `.select()` _not_ working for you, then we might be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

> At this point, the result is another feature collection without any columns.

The `columns:` information that is displayed by `print()`ing a collection in Earth Engine is an approximate value. If a name is present in it, then every feature in the collection has that property. If a name is absent, there may or may not be such a property on the features.

The only way to know for certain if properties are present is to inspect the individual features.

Comment: Thanks, this clarified the issue for me.